# ¿Cómo visualizar datos de un procedimiento almacenado dentro de una vista MVC.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de MVC.Net en dónde por medio de un formulario mando los datos necesarios para que me filtre la información que contengo en mi procedimiento almacenado. Mostraré lo trabajado:

Modelo:

```
public class Lineas
{
    public string Linea { get; set; }
    public decimal MesAnterior { get; set; }
    public decimal MesActual { get; set; }
    public decimal Diferencia { get; set; }
    public decimal Tolerancia { get; set; }
}
```

El método de mi controlador:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Lineas(string Linea, int? Mes, int? Año)
    {

        using (OpexDB db = new OpexDB())
        {
            var lineas = db.Database.SqlQuery<Lineas>("SP_NIVELES @NIVEL, @MES, @AÑO",
                                                                new SqlParameter("NIVEL", Linea),
                                                                new SqlParameter("MES", Mes),
                                                                new SqlParameter("AÑO", Año)).ToList();


            return View("Index", lineas);
        }
    }
```

Parte de mi vista:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Lineas", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                if (Model == null)
                {
                    <form id="lineas-form" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Lineas", "Home")">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Linea">Línea:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Linea" name="Linea">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Mes">Mes:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="Mes" name="Mes">
                                    <option value="1">Enero</option>
                                    <option value="2">Febrero</option>
                                    <option value="3">Marzo</option>
                                    <option value="4">Abril</option>
                                    <option value="5">Mayo</option>
                                    <option value="6">Junio</option>
                                    <option value="7">Julio</option>
                                    <option value="8">Agosto</option>
                                    <option value="9">Septiembre</option>
                                    <option value="10">Octubre</option>
                                    <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
                                    <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Año">Año:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Año" name="Año">
                            </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Obtener Datos</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Linea</th>
                                <th>Mes Anterior</th>
                                <th>Mes Actual</th>
                                <th>Diferencia</th>
                                <th>Tolerancia</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.Linea</td>
                                    <td>@item.MesAnterior</td>
                                    <td>@item.MesActual</td>
                                    <td>@item.Diferencia</td>
                                    <td>@item.Tolerancia</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <button id="volver-btn" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 hidden" onclick="toggleTableAndForm()">Volver</button>
             }
        }
```

Lo que son las propiedades de Linea y Diferencia me las muestra de manera correcta. El problema es en las propiedades de MesAnterior y MesActual que no me muestra un valor, Diferencia si me la muestra que es MesAnterior-MesActual y la propiedad de porcentaje se aplica si Diferencia es negativa.

Me lo muestra de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber en dónde es que estoy fallando o que me falto implementar para poder leer estos datos. Dentro de mi lenguaje de base de datos si muestra bien los datos, entonces asumo que el problema esta en el controlador, vista o modelo.

Comment: En tu clase `Linea` reemplaza los `decimal` por `object` y luego en la vista pones `@item.MesAnterior.ToString()` (lo mismo para los otros 3 casos). Prueba y me cuentas si resulta

Comment: De esa forma me genera el siguiente error. System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: Ok, eso quiere decir que el SP no te está retornando los datos, o que los nombre en tu clase `Linea` no son los correctos

Comment: Desconocía realmente que las propiedades de mi modelo debían coincidir meramente con el nombre de mis columnas de mi base de datos. Te agradezco, he estado con breakpoints pensando que el problema era otro.

Comment: Fantastico!! es que claro, de lo contrario no hay como saber qué valor corresponde a cada propiedad